# Single quotes being swapped for double quotes upon replace

Tags: python-3.x, string, postgresql, dataframe, escaping

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this

```
        orig_id modified_id original_term                   modified_term
1929    3668340 3578283     Advocate for clients'' needs.   Advocate for clients'' needs
```

You can see that I'm escaping the single quote (the reason being is that these strings are going to end up being part of a PostgreSql statement. I do this with

```
matches['original_term'] = matches['original_term'].map(lambda x: x.replace("'", "''"))
matches['modified_term'] = matches['modified_term'].map(lambda x: x.replace("'", "''"))
```

In order for this to be part of a SQL string, I convert these columns into a string of tuples, like so

```
orig_mod_pairs = str(tuple(zip(matches['original_term'], matches['modified_term'])))[1:-1]
```

This works well for all strings except the escaped ones. For instance, I see something like

```
('Advocacy and self-empowerment.', 'Advocacy and self-empowerment'), ('Advocacy and support services.', 'Advocacy and support services'), ('Advocacy for accessible and equitable mental health services.', 'Advocacy for accessible and equitable mental health services'), ('Advocacy groups.', 'Advocacy groups'), ("Advocate for clients'' needs.", "Advocate for clients'' needs")
```

But, as you can see, when we get to the escaped string, the single quotes around that substring "magically" turn into double quotes. What I want is to see single quotes throughout except for the escaped single quote. Something like

```
('Advocate for clients'' needs.', 'Advocate for clients'' needs')
```

Otherwise, PostgreSQL throws an error.

Ultimately, these tuples end up here

```
update_level1_string = f"""UPDATE associations_1
                           SET level_1_term = pairs.modified_term
                           FROM (VALUES {orig_mod_pairs}) as pairs (original_term, modified_term)
                           WHERE level_1_term = pairs.original_term;"""
```

Comment: It does not look like double quotes but 2 single quotes for an escape character.  If you use your mouse over in the text with what you say is double quotes, you can see that it is 2 different characters/2 single quotes.

Comment: OK, then why is this happening to this part of the string and not other parts? How can I only replace the `''` when it's an apostrophe?

Comment: I think he means the double quotes warping around the whole string

Comment: In any case, how can I prevent this situation from happening?

Comment: The problem afaik is that you are using str() which will escape characters using python rules, which doesn't work for PostgreSQL, could you please provide the way you insert the statements into your DBMS.

Comment: @Ianis, edited my question per your request.

Comment: @Ianis, enclose which string with `$$`? The SQL string?

Comment: How are you executing the query? I'd expect the DB-API driver to handle the escaping, if given the opportunity.